# C# SocketIOClientDotNet doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, websocket, socket.io

I am currently trying to connect to a website's websocket using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client with C# and it doesn't seem to work, I manged to get the equivalent code in JS to work, but I need it to work in C# as well and I have absolutely no clue what am I doing wrong.

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new IO.Options();
            options.Path = "/s";
            options.Transports = ImmutableList.Create<string>("websocket");
            options.Secure = true;
            options.ReconnectionDelay = 5000;
            options.Reconnection = true;
            options.Cookies.Add("do_not_share_this_with_anyone_not_even_staff", "cookie");
            options.Cookies.Add("PHPSESSID", "cookie");
            options.ExtraHeaders.Add("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36");
            var socket = IO.Socket(new Uri("wss://roulette.csgoempire.com/notifications"), options);

            socket.Connect();

            socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to empire.");
            });

            socket.On(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from empire.");
            });

            socket.On(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, (err) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Event Error");
            });

            socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, (err) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connect Error");
            });

        }
    }
```

The code does simply nothing, it runs, and immediately finishes with code 0. (I would like it to at least write the "Connected to empire").

Thank you and sorry for my ignorance /:

Comment: Try to add something at the end to prevent your app to stop. Like `Console.ReradLine()`

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your code. This will make sure your `Console.WriteLines` are being printed to the console and won't exit the console instantly.

Comment: Hey. Like I mentioned in the post it just finishes with a 0 exit code, it doesn't close the console immediately. It doesn't print the `Console.WriteLines` because I guess that it doesn't even connect to the websocket. But thank you anyways.